# Using grepl in R to search for an asterisk

Tags: r

I am reading a phrase into an R script as an argument.  If the phrase contains an asterisk (`*`), I do not want the script to run.

However, I am having issues recognising the asterisk when using grepl.  For example:

```
> asterisk="*"
> phrase1="hello"
> phrase2="h*llo"
> grepl(asterisk,phrase1)
[1] TRUE
> grepl(asterisk,phrase2)
[1] TRUE
```

The outcome for `grepl(asterisk,phrase1)` should be `FALSE`.  Does anyone know how I can get `grepl` to recognise if there is or isn't an asterisk in the phrase?

Comment: note https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk

Comment: Some others to watch out for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/399078/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
p <- c("Hello", "H*llo")
grepl("\\*", p)

[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

This works because the `*` asterisk has special meaning in a regular expresssion. Specifically, `*` means find zero or more of the previous element.

Thus you have to escape the asterisk using `\\*`. The double escape is necessary because the `\` already has the meaning of escape in R.

Comment: or `grepl("*",p,fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: I prefer this approach, but an alternative to avoid the use of the escape characters is `grepl("*", p, fixed=TRUE)`